# How to get Assembly source from Bin file?

Tags: disassembly, assembly

I have a binary file which is coded in assembly x86 and compiled with nasm. I used command

```
nasm file.asm -f bin -o file.bin
```

to compile it with nasm.
I deleted the source code from disk long time ago, but now I need that.

Is there any way to reverse the binary file?

Comment: Can you share the bin file?

Answer (score 2):

According to [nasmdoc](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10rc8/html/nasmdoc7.html)
the bin file doesn't have a definite structure. With a simple code like this

```
bits 32
default rel
section .rodata
x: db "foo", 0
pop eax
lea ebx, [x]
lea ebx, [y]
section .data
y: db "bar", 0
```

This in bin form assembles to

```
[/tmp] hd y.bin
00000000  66 6f 6f 00 58 8d 1d 00  00 00 00 8d 1d 14 00 00  |foo.X...........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 62 61 72 00                           |....bar.|
00000018
```

As you can see there's no definite structure in the output. If you know the architecture - 16(default)/32/64 you can directly load this file into something like IDA and with some interactive browsing around you can mark sections of this bin as code/data - this might take some time but IDA would recognize most of the code and you can dump the output to a simple asm file.

Update : Based on OPs link of the bin file

```
[rese] file file.bin
file.bin: DOS/MBR boot sector
```

This can be booted online - [here](http://copy.sh/v86/debug.html?profile=custom)
Its a simple demo of writing colorful text to display.
[image: boot]

Load it in IDA as 16-bit. It'll cleanly disassemble with comments.
With some editing it'll be compatible to nasm

```
                 mov     ah, 7
                 mov     al, 0
                 mov     dh, 18h
                 mov     dl, 50h
                 int     10h             ; - VIDEO - SCROLL PAGE DOWN
                                         ; AL = number of lines to scroll window (0 = blank whole window)
                                         ; BH = attributes to be used on blanked lines
                                         ; CH,CL = row,column of upper left corner of window to scroll
                                         ; DH,DL = row,column of lower right corner of window
                 mov     ah, 1
                 mov     cx, 2607h
                 int     10h             ; - VIDEO - SET CURSOR CHARACTERISTICS
                                         ; CH bits 0-4 = start line for cursor in character cell
                                         ; bits 5-6 = blink attribute
                                         ; CL bits 0-4 = end line for cursor in character cell
                 mov     ah, 0
                 mov     al, 13h
                 int     10h             ; - VIDEO - SET VIDEO MODE
                                         ; AL = mode
                 mov     si, 7C3Ah
                 mov     cl, 28h ; '('

 loc_1C:                                 ; CODE XREF: sub_0+31↓j
                                         ; sub_0+38↓j
                 mov     ah, 0Eh
                 mov     al, [si]
                 mov     bh, 0
                 mov     bl, cl
                 int     10h             ; - VIDEO - WRITE CHARACTER AND ADVANCE CURSOR (TTY WRITE)
                                         ; AL = character, BH = display page (alpha modes)
                                         ; BL = foreground color (graphics modes)
                 lodsb
                 hlt
                 inc     cl
                 cmp     cl, 37h ; '7'
                 jz      short loc_36
                 cmp     al, 0
                 jnz     short loc_1C

 loc_33:                                 ; CODE XREF: sub_0+34↓j
                 hlt
                 jmp     short loc_33

 loc_36:                                 ; CODE XREF: sub_0+2D↑j
                 mov     cl, 20h ; ' '
                 jmp     short loc_1C
aYouJustBecameA :  db 'You just became a victim of wncry.',0xD,0xA,0xD,0xA
                db 'Enjoy the zzzz.',0
pad:            times 398 db 0
                db 0x55
                db 0xaa
```

which when assembled matches the original bin file.

```
[rese] nasm -f bin -o y.bin y.asm
[rese] diff <(hd file.bin) <(hd y.bin)
[rese] sha1sum y.bin file.bin
d6d77852628f51961b30dd3f7a8f07281fd87f5b  y.bin
d6d77852628f51961b30dd3f7a8f07281fd87f5b  file.bin
```